# Accessing indexes in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.7, tabula-py

I am using tabula-py to extract a table from a pdf document like this:

```
rows = tabula.read_pdf('bank_statement.pdf', pandas_options={"header":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, pages='all', stream=True, lattice=True) 

rows
```

This gives an output like so:

```
[                                                   0
 0  Customer Statement\rxxxxxxx\rP...
 1  Print Date: April 12, 2020Address: 41 BAALE ST...
 2  Period: January 1, 2020 ­ April 12, 2020Openin...,
                                                    0
 0  Customer Statement\xxxxxxxx\rP...
 1  Print Date: April 12, 2020Address: 41 gg ST...,
              0          1            2          3          4          5  \
 0  03­Jan­2020          0  03­Jan­2020        NaN  50,000.00  52,064.00   
 1  10­Jan­2020          0  10­Jan­2020  25,000.00        NaN  27,064.00   
 2  10­Jan­2020          0  10­Jan­2020      25.00        NaN  27,039.00   
 3  10­Jan­2020          0  10­Jan­2020       1.25        NaN  27,037.75   
 4  20­Jan­2020  999921...  20­Jan­2020  10,000.00        NaN  17,037.75   
 5  23­Jan­2020  999984...  23­Jan­2020   4,050.00        NaN  12,987.75   
 6  23­Jan­2020          0  23­Jan­2020   1,000.00        NaN  11,987.75   
 7  24­Jan­2020          0  24­Jan­2020   2,000.00        NaN   9,987.75   
 8  24­Jan­2020          0  24­Jan­2020        NaN  30,000.00  39,987.75   

                                                    6  
 0  TRANSFER BETWEEN\rCUSTOMERS Via GG from\r...  
 1  NS Instant Payment Outward\r000013200110121...  
 2  COMMISSION\r0000132001101218050000326...\rNIP ...  
 3     VALUE ADDED TAX VAT ON NIP\rTRANSFER FOR 00001  
 4  CASH WITHDRAWAL FROM\rOTHER ATM ­210674­ ­4420...  
 5  POS/WEB PURCHASE\rTRANSACTION ­845061­\r­80405...  
 6  Airtime Purchase MBANKING­\r101CT0000000001551...  
 7  Airtime Purchase MBANKING­\r101CT0000000001552...  
 8  TRANSFER BETWEEN\rCUSTOMERS\r00001520012412113...  ,
```

What I want from this pdf starts from index 2. So I run

```
rows[2]
```

And I get a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want indexes from 2 till the last index. I did

```
rows[2:]
```

But I am getting a list and not the expected dataframe.

```
[             0          1            2          3          4          5  \
 0  03­Jan­2020          0  03­Jan­2020        NaN  50,000.00  52,064.00   
 1  10­Jan­2020          0  10­Jan­2020  25,000.00        NaN  27,064.00   
 2  10­Jan­2020          0  10­Jan­2020      25.00        NaN  27,039.00   
 3  10­Jan­2020          0  10­Jan­2020       1.25        NaN  27,037.75   
 4  20­Jan­2020  999921...  20­Jan­2020  10,000.00        NaN  17,037.75   
 5  23­Jan­2020  999984...  23­Jan­2020   4,050.00        NaN  12,987.75   
 6  23­Jan­2020          0  23­Jan­2020   1,000.00        NaN  11,987.75   
 7  24­Jan­2020          0  24­Jan­2020   2,000.00        NaN   9,987.75   
 8  24­Jan­2020          0  24­Jan­2020        NaN  30,000.00  39,987.75   

                                                    6  
 0  TRANSFER BETWEEN\rCUSTOMERS Via gg from\r...  
 1  bi Instant Payment Outward\r000013200110121...  
 2  COMMISSION\r0000132001101218050000326...\rNIP ...  
 3     VALUE ADDED TAX VAT ON NIP\rTRANSFER FOR 00001  
 4  CASH WITHDRAWAL FROM\rOTHER ATM ­210674­ ­4420...  
 5  POS/WEB PURCHASE\rTRANSACTION ­845061­\r­80405...
```

Please do I solve this? I need a dataframe for indexes starting at 2 and onwards.

Comment: Shouldn't be rows[2][2:]?

Comment: Still only fetches the second index and infact, skips the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this behaviour because `rows` is a `list` and *[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1650240)* a list produces another **list**. When you access an element at a specific index, you get the **object** at that index; in this case, a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe) object.

The [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) library ships with a [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas-concat) function that can combine multiple `DataFrame` objects into one -- I believe this is what you want to do -- such that you have:

```
import pandas as pd


df_combo = pd.concat([rows[2], rows[3], rows[4], rows[5] ...])
```

Even better:

```
df_combo = pd.concat(rows[2:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-extract-multiple-tables-from-a-pdf-through-python-and-tabula-py-6f642a9ee673

The best way to go about what you're trying to achieve is by reading the table and returning the response as JSON, loop through the json objects for your lists.